# Proving Uniform Convergence 2

Tags: real-analysis

Need to prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2} $, for $x\in[-1,1]$
is it enough to say this is less than $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $ for positive x and the alternating series test for negative x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in[-1,1]$ we have

$$ \frac{|x^n|}{n^2}=\frac{|x|^n}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}.$$